# Save cursors in temporary table

Tags: function, postgresql, cursor, plpgsql, temporary

I'm an absolute noob and couldn't find the answer to this one.
How can I add the result into a temporary table?
Perhaps you guys have some tips for me to improve my code as well?

I created a function here with cursors through the results. But I need to:

```
drop function if exists non_married_presidents();
create or replace function non_married_presidents()
returns varchar as $$
declare
    c_emp cursor for
        select name, birth_year from president
        where id not in(select pres_id from pres_marriage);
begin


    for emp in c_emp loop
        raise notice 'name: %, birth_year: %', emp.name, emp.birth_year;
    end loop;
end;
$$language plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
select non_married_presidents();
```

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> How can I add the result into a temporary table?

You may be overthinking this. Just use `CREATE TEMP TABLE AS ...`

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_tbl AS
-- INSERT INTO tmp_tbl (name, birth_year) -- or insert into existing table
SELECT name, birth_year FROM president p
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pres_marriage WHERE pres_id = p.id);
```

You don't need a cursor. It's a rare occasion that an explicit cursor would be the best option in plpgsql.

While being at it, `NOT IN` is a construct best avoided:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)